# Dialogflow agent responding differently when testing in google home mini

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I created an agent and started testing it in google assistant in my phone. When testing same agent in google home some intents are responding differently and weirdly. I used same account for both google assistant in my phone and google home. Also when i tested in other phones google assistant it is working fine. I do not know where the problem lies whether with device or agent or is there any cache problems? By the way I did reboot and tried but the problem still exists.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "intents are responding differently and weirdly"? If possible share some details on your intents or code if you use any.

Comment: I am getting a different response rather than response i gave it for in inline editor. Response of other intent is coming to that intent, but it happens only on google home not in google assistant.

Comment: If response is coming form Fulfillment you should make sure it is readable by Google Home (If an intent works for GA it doesn't mean it will work for all integrated platforms). If you want know what the exact problem is I would recommend to post the code for the intent that has problem.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I figured out the problem after going through the logs. The problem is that google home is unable to capture the utterance clearly. For example the intent gets invoked when user says 'veg biryani' but what it captures is 'veg biriyani'. So since there is a difference in spelling between 'biryani' and 'biriyani', it is only taking 'veg' as slot value for which other intent will be invoked. So i added word 'veg biriyani' to synonym of entity and problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I figured out the problem after going through the logs. The problem is that google home is unable to capture the utterance clearly. For example the intent gets invoked when user says 'veg biryani' but what it captures is 'veg biriyani'. So since there is a difference in spelling between 'biryani' and 'biriyani', it is only taking 'veg' as slot value for which other intent will be invoked. So i added word 'veg biriyani' to synonym of entity and problem solved.